# Hidden Services and the "Eyes"

Tags: onion-services, location

What can be done to improve anonymity of Hidden Service ag ainst the "Eyes" or intelligence agencies like NSA, GCHQ

I'm not loking for a bullet proof solution but only steps an operator can take to improve anonymity of his HS against big a dversaries

Answer (score 1):

Riseup.net has a HS best practices guide which they use for their own hidden services.

Can definitely recommend it.

Check it out:
https://riseup.net/en/security/network-security/tor/onionservices-best-practices